# Zoom sobre SVG, sin cambiar coordenadas de polígonos

Tags: javascript, svg, zoom

Tengo un código, donde dentro de un svg, "dibujo" polígonos, trayendo las coordenadas de la base de datos.
Dentro de svg tengo una imagen, que donde se dibujan los polígonos encima.

Eso funciona todo de diez, crea los polígonos, da estilos, etc.

Lo que yo quiero, es poder hacer zoom(con scroll mouse) en la imagen, pero que el polígono no pierda las coordenadas, o sea, que si la imagen la agrando 10%, el polígono tmb se agrande y quede ubicado en la parte donde está destinado primeramente. Luego, dentro de la imagen "hecha zoom" poder moverme(estilo googlemaps)

Pongo, los códigos.

HTML tengo así:

```
<style>
    polygon {
        stroke-width: 4;
        stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        pointer-events: visible;
        cursor: hand;
        transition: fill 1;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
    }

    polygon:hover {
        fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
</style>
<div class="contenedor">
    <svg id="generalsvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" data-imgsrc="lotes.jpg" width="100%" height="1233">
        <image xlink:href="lotes.jpg"  x="0" y="0"></image>            
    </svg>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="svg.js"></script>
```

JavaSript así:

```
listardibujossvg();

function listardibujossvg() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'listar-dibujo.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        const dibujos = JSON.parse(response);
        dibujos.forEach(dibujo => {
            var coord = JSON.parse(dibujo.coordenadas);
            var iddibujo = JSON.parse(dibujo.id_terreno);
            var coord = JSON.stringify(coord);
            coord = coord.replace(/[^.,0-9]/g, '');

            var poligono = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
            poligono.className = 'poligono';
            poligono.id = iddibujo;
            poligono.setAttribute("points", coord);
            poligono.setAttribute("onclick", "mandarId(this.id)")
            poligono.setAttribute("style", "cursor: hand;" /*"fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:1"*/ )
            document.getElementById("generalsvg").appendChild(poligono);
            console.log(coord);
            console.log(coord.length);
        });
    }
});
}

function mandarId(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: El elemento svg tiene que tener un atributo viewBox. Además tendrías que borrar la altura height y la anchura width. Por defecto la anchura de un elemento svg que tiene un atributo viewBox es de 100%. Para hacer zoom en una zona del lienzo svg puedes cambiar el valor del atributo viewBox. Por favor lea acerca d[el atributo viewBox](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/svg/viewport-y-viewbox.phphttp://w3.unpocodetodo.info/svg/viewport-y-viewbox.php), también acerca de [Guardar las proporciones en SVG](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/svg/preserveaspectratio.php)

Comment: Me abría gustado contestar a tu pregunta.No puedo hacerlo porque considero que el código que publicas es irrelevante

Answer (score -1):

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

la propiedad  `viewBox`  del svg me refería que actuases sobre la propiedad verbos para hacer zoom

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta